# Enabling Crashlytics with Firebase Management API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, crashlytics

We are developing large number of customized Android and iOS applications for our customers. We have used Fabric to manage the crashes and Google Cloud Messaging to send push messages for the applications. We have now migrated all those applications to Google Firebase.

We are using Firebase Management REST API to create the applications into Firebase enabled projects from our PHP backend. For Android apps we use methods `projects.androidApps.create` and `projects.androidApps.getConfig` to get access to the application `google-services.json`. We include that to the build, which passes without errors and the push messages work without a problem. However, the Crashlytics side does not get enabled. In Firebase console there is only a wizard to set up a new Firebase app. When running it, it gives impression that Craslytics will get enabled, when the app starts using Firebase, but it is not.

Is there an API to enable the Crashlytics for an app? We can use REST or PHP based API in the backend. Also, if there is a client side API to awaken Crashlytics, we can use that too.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, though with the new Crashlytics SDKs we are looking at ways of changing this behavior. In the future, as soon as we receive a crash event we will enable the Crashlytics dashboard. The timeline for this though, is unknown.

Comment: Actually, we realized that the Android was still using Crashlytics beta SDK. After upgrading to the release version, the Crashlytics dashboard got initialized automatically. Unfortunately the same trick did not work for iOS. Anyway, I tend to assume it should start working like Android. Therefore REST API would not be needed after all.